# Length of a curve on $S^2$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

$1.$ Could any one tell me what is the shortest distance between $2$ points on $S^2$?

$2.$ Could any one tell me how to measure explicitly a length of a curve on the $S^2$ using polar co-ordinates?

Thank you very much for the help and discussion ahead.

Comment: There is no shortest distance between two different points of $S^2$: there are pairs of distinct points as close as you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to calculate the shortest distance between two points is to join the points by curves which are called "minimal geodesics".  To find a minimal geodesic, you find a great circle which contains both the points.  This is done by forming a circular segment between the centre of the sphere and the two points.  Then the standard formula applies: $$l = r \theta = \theta$$

To compute $\theta$, we use the dot product rule $$ \cos \theta = \frac{a \cdot b}{\|a\| \|b\|} = a \cdot b$$ knowing that both $\|a\| = \|b\| = 1$.  Therefore

$$l = \arccos(a \cdot b)$$

To answer the second part of your question, suppose the curve you are given is defined by a curve $r : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.  The standard formula for arclength of a curve will give you the curves length:

$$ l = \int_0^1 ||r'(t)|| dt $$

Suppose now $s(t) = (1, s_{\theta}(t), s_{\phi}(t))$ is instead presented in spherical coordinates.  We then wish to know the corresponding arc length when converted into cartesian coordinates.  Simply define $$r(t) := (\sin (s_{\theta}(t)) \cos(s_{\phi}(t)), \sin (s_{\theta}(t)) \sin( s_{\phi}(t)), cos(s_{\theta}(t))) $$
and use the above formula.

Comment: I do not understand the answer of 2nd part, please make me understand by an example please please

Comment: Suppose the curve in spherical coordinates is $$s(t) = (\rho(t), \theta(t), \phi(t)) = (1, t, -t)$$ for $t \in [0,1]$.  Then the curve in Cartesian coordinates is given by: $$r(t) = (\sin t \cos t, - \sin t \sin t, \cos t)$$

Computing $$r'(t) = (\cos 2t, -\cos 2t, - \sin t)$$ and so $$ l = \int_0^1 \| r'(t) \| dt = \int_0^1 \sqrt{2 \cos^2 2t + \sin^2 t} dt $$

Comment: let $r$ be the magnitude of a vector in $3D$ with Spherical co-ordinate $(r,\theta,\phi)$ and cartesian coordinates is $(x,y,z)$, whose angle with $z$ axis is $\phi$ and projection of the vector makes angle $\theta$ with $x$ axis. We know the  the relations $$x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$$ $$y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi$$ $$z=r\cos\phi$$

Now $\gamma(t):[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a curve $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ Now could you confirm me that lenghth of the curve is given by the formulae $$l_{\gamma}=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dz}{dt})^2}$$? if yes how did we come to this

Comment: and from the above relation of cartesian and spherical co ordinates I calculated that the lenght is given by $l_{\gamma}=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{(\frac{dr}{dt})^2+r^2(\frac{d\theta}{dt})^2}$, am I right? and what wil be the upper and lower limit of tis integration?

Comment: why $s(t) = (1, s_{\theta}(t), s_{\phi}(t))$ ? why first component u took $1$?

Comment: Because it lies on the unit sphere

Comment: and yes, that is the formula for length of a curve in cartesian coordinates.  It's just pythagoras theorem on an infinitesimal scale

Comment: Could you please give answer of this one? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328387/shortest-distance-between-any-two-points-on-s2?noredirect=1#comment709762_328387